# How can I add an Authorization header to every http request?

Tags: javascript, authentication, http-headers, jwt

I'm looking at retro-fitting JWT stateless authentication to an existing web application.

I'm considering using single-use tokens as well as setting an expiry time. The server will return a fresh token with each response.

My questions are:

- How can I automatically append the additional header to every request? It needs to go with every request so that new one can be issued.
- Would it be correct to return the new token in the response header and not the body?

Comment: What API is the existing code using to make requests? `jQuery.ajax`? `fetch`? `XMLHttpRequest`? Something else?

Comment: Is 'none' a valid answer? This is just a website and I think perhaps I want to intercept every http(s) request to attach the token...

Comment: You want this for all requests automatically triggered by the browser, including things like stylesheets and images? Then you're pretty much limited to cookies or HTTP Basic Auth.

Comment: Agreed, bad idea. Time to rethink.

Answer (score 0):

I try to answer you. I used jwt saving it in cookies, I put you here a very interesting link, I hope you can help [Where store JWT](https://stormpath.com/blog/where-to-store-your-jwts-cookies-vs-html5-web-storage)

If you want to put in every request you must write a wrapper around Jquery.ajax or XMLHttpRequest

Comment: Unless I've misunderstood, this looks like advice on local jwt storage, which isn't a problem I'm trying to solve.